# One liner to show CPU, RAM and HDD usage

Tags: command-line, monitoring

I've seen a few posts wanting the same regarding usage, however the answers ALWAYS refer to installing some third party tool.

I do not want to install anything.

Any one liners? The following would be a nice output:

```
CPU 11% RAM 20% HDD 85%
```

Comment: Is HDD usage the percentage how full it is or how busy it is?

Comment: @ByteCommander Both? :) On a serious note, the capacity though. If both that would be nice.

Comment: Sigh....... :-/

Comment: @ByteCommander By capacity I mean "how full it is" if I wasn't clear :)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use this

```
echo "CPU `LC_ALL=C top -bn1 | grep "Cpu(s)" | sed "s/.*, *\([0-9.]*\)%* id.*/\1/" | awk '{print 100 - $1}'`% RAM `free -m | awk '/Mem:/ { printf("%3.1f%%", $3/$2*100) }'` HDD `df -h / | awk '/\// {print $(NF-1)}'`"
```

The output is

```
CPU 7.4% RAM 33.9% HDD 94%
```

Comment: the HD part is going to suck if you have many partitions.

Comment: `df -h /` part of command line shows the statistics about `/` partition. You can repeat `df -h` command and substitute `/` with the mount point you need to monitor.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.  CPU is always 91%, I have no idea where it gets that from. // And RAM includes buffers and cache making it look like it's exhausted.  I do use 97.8% RAM, but there's still 67.5% free.

Comment: I figured the CPU issue out.  It's a localization issue.  The idle is 45.9% for me, but it's printed as 45,9.

Comment: Must be something wrong with my top(1), the CPU % is stuck.  I have to use `top -bn2` and put a `tail -n1` after the grep. :-/

Comment: @OskarSkog Your `top` is alright. CPU usage can not be measured at the current point in time, it must be measured over a short timespan. When `top` runs the first iteration, it shows the average usage since the last reboot. Starting with the second iteration it shows the actual current usage since the previous iteration. And if you have problems with localization, you can put `LC_ALL=C` in front of the command to use default English localization (number formats etc, not language).

Comment: @MKay:  You may want to replace `top -bn1 | grep "Cpu(s)"` with `top -bn2 | grep "Cpu(s)" | tail -n1`.  The former will display a long term average as pointed out by Byte Commander.

Comment: Not 100% accurate as it adds swap on top of current RAM usage and then gives a percentage but it's close enough. Thanks for the code, it lead me to a memory hogging program which did nothing else...

Comment: @OskarSkog Or something like `top -bn2 -d 0.1 | grep "Cpu(s)" | tail -n1` to get a fast result. Without the custom delay `-d` top will run for three seconds.

Comment: @scai:  Great suggestion.  However, it seems that at least the top(1) I have only uses the integer part of the delay for measuring CPU utilization.  But can you confirm it works on recent versions of Ubuntu?

Comment: @OskarSkog I'm using Debian with top from procps-ng 3.3.12.

Answer (score 9):

For CPU usage (average of `(user+system)/(user+system+idle)` times over 0.1 seconds):

```
(grep 'cpu ' /proc/stat;sleep 0.1;grep 'cpu ' /proc/stat)|awk -v RS="" '{print "CPU "($13-$2+$15-$4)*100/($13-$2+$15-$4+$16-$5)"%"}'
```

For RAM usage (`(total-available)/total`):

```
awk '/MemTotal/{t=$2}/MemAvailable/{a=$2}END{print 100-100*a/t"%"}' /proc/meminfo
```

For HDD usage (only of the volume mounted as `/`):

```
df | awk '/ \/$/{print "HDD "$5}'
```

Comment: Interesting, there's less memory available than what `free -m | head -n3 | tail -n1' reports as free memory.

Comment: @OskarSkog Can you share your output of that command? For me it simply prints the Swap total/used/free line, which is not relevant here. Maybe you meant something else, or your `free` command still uses the old output format with separate -/+ buffers/cache line...

Comment: My free uses the old format: https://oskog97.com/sshin/free-output.png  What's changed?

Comment: @OskarSkog The "-/+ buffers/cache" line got removed and now there is an additional column "available" in the "Mem" row instead. From `man free`: "*Estimation  of  how much memory is available for starting new applications, without swapping. Unlike the data provided by the cache or free fields, this field takes into account page cache and also that not all reclaimable memory  slabs  will be reclaimed due to items being in use MemAvailable in /proc/meminfo, available on kernels 3.14, emulated on kernels 2.6.27+, otherwise the same as free)*"